# rotation of unsigned char by n bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am trying to rotate an unsigned char by 'n' bits. But I am not getting the desired result. This is my code

```
void left_rotate(unsigned char a, int no){
        // no - number of times to rotate
        printf("%d\n", ((a << no) | (a >> (8-no))));
}
```

I am calling this function from mail as follows

```
unsigned char a = 'A';
left_rotate(a, 2);
```

I expected the following output

```
//'A' = 65 = 01000001
// I am rotating in left direction by two times
// a << 2 = 00000100
// a >> 6 = 00000001
(00000100 | 00000001 = 00000101 = 5 in decimal)
```

But I got a different output

```
// The output in my screen = 100000101 = 261 in decimal
```

How did that 1 in MSB creep in? I am using an unsigned char as data type. So it shouldnt exceed 8 bits. Can someone please explain this?

Thanks

Chid

Comment: You're shifting into (or through) the sign bit of a signed type (`char`). This is **undefined behavior**. Use `unsigned char` instead.

Comment: @WhozCraig Where is he shifting a signed `char`?

Comment: @H2CO3 in my coffee-deprived intellectually-fog-laidened head. Thanks for keeping me honest, sir =P

Comment: @WhozCraig No problem :P Although you were pretty close, actually! Bon appetit for your coffee.

Comment: @H2CO3 Heh. not really. I totally forgot about the promotion. Subtle question. gotta +1 it.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, I was thinking about that too. I didn't quite get it either, TBH.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `<<` promotes its arguments to `unsigned int`, you need to mask off the upper bits of the shift result:

```
printf("%d\n", (((a << no) & 0xFF) | (a >> (8-no))));
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/pq4Ejs) (prints `5`).

Comment: I wish I could update *all* your answers just for your avatar pic; a rrod. That is *outstanding*. Alas, this easily deserves the up-vote regardless.